# Using methods in Linq expressions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am using LINQ in a Web API project that accesses the database with Entity Framework.  I created my API controllers using the scaffolding

We do not want the Web API to expose our EF model classes so we are using DTO's instead. I've modified the controller methods to use the DTO's and have "Translate" methods that copies values between the model class and DTO for a particular entity and I use that in several methods within the class.

For this post I'm using a simple Person class with three properties: FirstName, LastName, MiddleName.

```
public IQueryable<PersonDto> GetPersons()
{
    var personDtos = from p in db.Persons
    order by p.LastName, p.FirstName
    select new PersonDto()
    {
        FirstName = p.FirstName,
        LastName = p.LastName,
        MiddleName = p.MiddleName
    };

    return personDtos;
}

private PersonDto Translate(Person p)
{
    if (person == null)
        return null;

    return new PersonDto()
    {
        FirstName = p.FirstName,
        LastName = p.LastName,
        MiddleName = p.MiddleName
    }
}
```

As you can see there's a refactoring opportunity there by calling the Translate method in the LINQ expression, as below:

```
public IQueryable<PersonDto> GetPersons()
{
    var personDtos = from p in db.Persons
    order by p.LastName, p.FirstName
    select Translate(p);

    return personDtos;
}
```

Seems good, except when I run it, I get an exception:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Translate'

Is there a way to make this work? Some of our classes in our data model have quite a few properties so it would be good to call the Translate method here if it is possible.

Comment: it's better to use Projection, I preffer to use AutoMapper to transfer Entity to myModel,it's very easy to use, for Example db.Persons.Where(...).ProjectTo<MyNewPersonModel>().ToList().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's cause `LINQ to Entities` has to translate the expression into SQL query and your method can't be translated since it has no idea how to. One way is to call `AsEnumerable()` and have your method called on `LINQ to objects` rather

```
var personDtos = from p in db.Persons.AsEnumerable()
order by p.LastName, p.FirstName
select Translate(p);
```

Comment: Looks like I'd need to cast the personDtos.AsQueryable() to get this to work.  Not a big deal, however, I'm not sure if that is as efficient as using var persons =  from p in db.persons orderby p.LastName, p.FirstName and then looping through the results and calling translate on each one.  I also was going to use Translate on the method to get a single Person, but found this to be easier: var person = await db.Persons.SingleOrDefaultAsync(p=>p.id==id); var personDto = Translate(person);

Answer (score 1):

LinqToEntities does not know how to change your method Translate() into something that can be executed in the database. [AsEnumerable()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) will ensure that processing happens client side after it is called:

```
var personDtos = (from p in db.Persons
    order by p.LastName, p.FirstName
    select p)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Translate(p);
```

will get you quite close. However, Translate() takes a single person, not an IEnumerable of them. You could change it to

```
private IEnumerable<PersonDto> Translate(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
{
    if (persons == null) yield break;

    foreach (var p in persons)
    {
        yield return new PersonDto()
        {
            FirstName = p.FirstName,
            LastName = p.LastName,
            MiddleName = p.MiddleName
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use **ProjectTo** a Queryable Extension of the **AutoMapper**.

```
db.Persons.ProjectTo<PersonDTO>().ToList()
```

Comment: This is very close to a "Link only" answer.  Some samples or additional information would be helpful.